# What is the expected value E(C) that the insurance company is expected to pay?

Tags: probability-distributions

Discrete probability 
When all factors are taken into account, an insurance company estimates that the probability of the owners’ of certain house making a claim for $\$5000$ is $0.1$. Furthermore the company estimates the probability of a $\$450,000$ claim( total loss of the home) is $0.005$. Let $X$ represent the dollar amount the company will pay on a claim in a given year. What values can $X$ take on?

I just want to know if I’m doing this correctly all I would do is add to find the $x$ right  which would look like $5000(0.1)+450,000(0.005)=2750$

Comment: Can you fix the formatting in your post? It is very difficult to read.

Comment: The title and first paragraph ask very different questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly calculated the expected value the company will pay out.  That is not what the question asks, though it is what the title asks.  The question asks what amounts the company might pay.  There should be three or four of them.  I don't think the question is clear whether one of them is possible.